# What does c<CR> do?

Tags: key-bindings

What does <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (not <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>) do in Vim? I didn't have any mapping about it and it behaves like the `S` command. See below image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<CR>` motion in Normal mode moves to the next line.

When you use that motion with an operator (such as `c`), it will select the current line and the next.

You can find (a little bit more) under [`:help <CR>`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3CCR%3E), which says:

> `[count]` lines downward, on the first non-blank character **linewise**.

The "linewise" part is the interesting one, indicating it acts on full lines when used with an operator.

So when you use `c<CR>`, Vim will replace the current line and the next and leave you in Insert mode to type a new line to replace them.

The `+` motion is a synonym for `<CR>`, so `c+` will do the same as `c<CR>`. (You'll find `+`, `<CR>` and `CTRL-M` are listed together in the same help entry.)